# Combining for loops, changing to "while loop", keeping function

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Is there a simple way to make these these three loops into one? And then change them to "while loops" while maintaining the same function?

I have tried switching the data into this:

```
{ run = true; counter = 1; while (run == true) /* or while (run) */ {document.write (counter);
counter++; if (counter > 3) run = false; } // end loop /* How many times will this loop go? */ }
```

But only get a blank page.

Here is the original "for loop" code ;

```
//numbers divisible by 5
for (i=1; i<=50; i++)  {
if (i%5 == 0) document.write ("number divisible by five is:  " + i + "<br />") ;
} //for
document.write  ("========================<br />");  //seperator

//numbers divisible by 7
for (i=1; i<=50; i++)  {
if (i%7==0) && (i%2!=0) ) document.write ("number divisible by seven is:  " + i + "<br />") ;
} //for
document.write  ("========================<br />");  //seperator

//numbers divisible by 9
for (i=1; i<=50; i++)  {
if (i%9==0) && (i%2==0) ) document.write ("number divisible by nine is:  " + i + "<br />") ;
} //for
document.write  ("========================<br />");  //seperator
```

Comment: Add a tag to what language you're using. Also write what you've tried / errors you're getting.

Comment: You can put code from second and thors loop into first. I'm not sure what do you think by changing loop to while loop

Comment: Why are  removing / keeping even numbers for 7 and 9?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially code golf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the loops, put the three if statements into one single loop from 1 to 50.

To convert the for loop to a while loop, a direct translation looks like so

```
 i = 1;  // variable 
while ( i<=50)  {  // condition 
    if (i%5 == 0) document.write ("number divisible by five is:  " + i + "<br />") ;
    // more if statements 
    i++;  // increment 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
var divisions = {
    five: [],
    seven:[],
    nine: []
};

for(i = 1; i <= 50; i ++;){
    if(i % 5 == 0) divisions.five.push(i);
    if((i % 7 == 0) && (i % 2 != 0)) divisions.seven.push(i);
    if((i % 9 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0)) divisions.nine.push(i);
}

divisions.five.forEach(function(number){
    document.write('number divisible by 5 is:' + number);
});

document.write  ("========================<br />");  //seperator

divisions.seven.forEach(function(number){
    document.write('number divisible by 7 is:' + number);
});

document.write  ("========================<br />");  //seperator

divisions.nine.forEach(function(number){
    document.write('number divisible by 9 is:' + number);
});

document.write  ("========================<br />");  //seperator
```

I haven't tested this, wrote it in the textbox here, you should get the general idea.